# Помощь в составлении запроса Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Ребят помогите составить запрос mysql к базе.

Есть две таблицы, в одной таблице хранится дата в другой количество показов. Суть такова нужно посчитать количество показов допустим за 3 дня. Все показы хранятся в одной строке таблицы.

Пример:
id
text
cont_numm (это показы)

---

Дата создания записи находится в другой таблице в поле date

Всю голову уже сломил не могу понять как высчитать.

Comment: Это делается JOIN`ом, для этого добавьте в таблицу с показами еще одно поле date_id по которому буду соединяться таблицы

Comment: поле добавил, можете мне помочь составить запрос?

Answer (score 0):

Вот у меня есть две таблицы

Первая таблица с постами (posts со столбцами: 
`id`, `post_id`,`post_name`,`post_date` TIMESTAMP можно и обычный DATE)

Вторая таблица с счетчиком просмотров (post_views со столбцами: `id`,`post_id`,`post_views`)
   Осталось их соединить запросом используя JOIN и получишь показы за несколько дней в данном случае за 3.

```
SELECT * FROM posts AS p
JOIN post_views AS pv ON p.post_id = pv.post_id
WHERE p.post_date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY )
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как теперь вывести само количество просмотров?

Comment: У меня при данном запросе выводит пустоту

Comment: Если вам нужно чисто количество тогда вместо * в SELECT используйте SUM(pv.post_views)

Comment: как показывало пустоту так и показывает((( добавил то что написали добавить в итоге никаких изменений

Comment: Можете подронее все расписать и как вы делаете, таблицы, какие в них данные запросы и тд. А то так очень сложно подсказать в чем проблема

Comment: вот мой код `$count_boards = $db->super_query("
SELECT SUM(pv.news_read) FROM " . PREFIX . "_post AS p
JOIN " . PREFIX . "_post_extras AS pv ON p.id = pv.eid
WHERE p.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY ) ");

$count_boards = $count_boards['news_read'];

echo $count_boards;`

Comment: У вас библеотека или фреймворк какой-то?

Comment: Меня лично это смущает `$count_boards = $count_boards['news_read'];`

Comment: у меня cms, сразу скажу функция запроса данных работает отлично. Вот только не могу понять почему выдает пустое поле

Comment: как тогда вытянуть данные если смущает это? `$count_boards = $count_boards['news_read'];`

Comment: Попробуйте лучше объявить другую переменную и присвоить ее результату $count_boards. Скорее всего он должен выдать массив, потому еще лучше использовать `print_r`

Comment: Это в принципе аналог если бы я делал так, `$count = $row['news_read'];

Comment: Я переменные менял, толку никакого не было

Comment: А что за cms у нас?

Comment: datalife engine

Comment: Я над собой в шоке небольшом, всегда не возникало проблем, а тут на тебе, но у меня иногда бывает небольшие недопонимания когда составляю именно  запрос mysql

Comment: Вот кстати что у меня print выдает Array ( [SUM(pv.news_read)] => ) null

Comment: Я не знаю как устроено в DLE, но скорее всего, super_squery возвращает resource. Тоесть нажо почитать доку и посмотреть может у них там есть свой какой-нибудь `mysql_fetch_*`